# Java - Is there any Design Pattern available for invoking custom code business logic after executing my core business logic

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns

We are developing core component, for few business scenarios we developed custom code for each scenario. 
we want to invoke those custom code business logic after executing my core business logic in configurable way without code modification in core component.

Is there any design pattern available for this scenario?

We are using the Spring Framework, is there any feature available init?

Example Code:

Core Module:

Core.java

```
public String save (Map<String,String> map){
// my business logic here to insert into to core table
}
```

Custom Module:

Entity1Custom.java

```
public String customSave(Map<String,String> map){
// my custom save logic only for Entity1
}
```

Entity2Custom.java

```
public String customSave(Map<String,String> map){
// my custom save logic only for Entity2
}
```

How to invoke custom Entity1 and Entity2 method after executing my core save method, in configurable way so that in future if any more entity gets added then I should not change my code.

Comment: You should write some code. Leave the *design pattern* to be used aside for now.

Comment: You might look at a factory pattern but I agree with @CKing writing code that solves your issue first and fit a pattern second.

Comment: Standard OO design should handle this, right?  Put the core logic in an abstract class that defers the custom code to an abstract method.

Comment: @Brick Exactly my thoughts. There is a difference between *design* and *design-patterns*.

Comment: @Cking - I can write some code but I want it should be one time and it should for all upcoming scenarios

Comment: @Pandian What I meant was, show us some sample code (pseudo-code) we can use as a reference to understand your situation. Also, design can evolve once you write the initial code.

Comment: @Brick purpose of Core logic is different from custom logic. Here core is business logic and custom logic could be anything like publish event or just log. Then why should the core be abstract class.

Comment: [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) comes to mind.

Without seeing an example, it's hard to say what would be best.

Comment: @Pandian This is exactly why I am asking you to write some code. So that we know what you are looking for rather than suggesting something randomly!

Comment: @CKing- Sample code added

Comment: @Pandian Why are the methods static? That seems to defeat you. The answer by kjj below is not unique but seems much better and uses nothing more than OO design. I'd have used an abstract class rather than an interface with a default implementation, but they are heading in the same direction.

Comment: @Brick - Alright I removed static keyword

Answer (score 0):

An example of a simple thing you can use (Java 8 example with default methods but you can adapt easily):

```
public interface BusinessProcessor {

    default void doBefore() {

    }

    void doCoreBusiness();

    default void doAfter() {

    }
}

public class MyCoreBusiness implements BusinessProcessor {

    @Override
    public void doCoreBusiness() {
        // Do core business there
    }

}

public class MyCustomExtendedBusiness extends MyCoreBusiness {

    @Override
    public void doBefore() {
        // Do something before
    }

}
```

Now, as explained in your question's comments, there is no need of a specific design pattern to do this, Object concept is enought. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variant, which is similar to the the one by @kjj but avoids the default implementation on the interface.

```
public class CoreLogic {
    protected void doCoreLogic() {
        // Core logic here
    }

    protected void doSpecificLogic {
        // Leave this implementation empty in case
        // some subclass doesn't need it.  Alternatively,
        // make it abstract (and the the class abstract too)
        // to force subclasses to provide an implementation.
    } 

    public void doAction {
        doCoreLogic();
        doSpecificLogic(); // Works even if this method is abstract
    }
}

public class SpecificLogic1 extends CoreLogic {
    protected void doSpecificLogic() {
        // Specific logic here.
    }
}
```

Note that, as others have also mentioned, this isn't so much a "design pattern" as just basic OO principles at work.

Comment: I do code change if I come up with SpecificLogic2 in future, but i don't do code change

Comment: @Pandian I cannot understand your comment? If you come up with SpecificLogic2, then you write a new subclass of CoreLogic and leave SpeicifcLogic1. Surely if you come up with new logic, you have to write code that captures that logic somewhere....

Comment: @ Brick - Assume we have more than one SpecificLogic1 classes extends CoreLogic now which class doSpecificLogic() method will execute?

Comment: The one that on instantiate in each case. I looked at your profile, and it claims that you've been doing Java for a while, so I'm not sure where the confusion is here. If you were a beginner, I'd say you need to learn basic Java.  As it stands, I think there's some other misunderstanding about what you're trying to do. Based on comments from others, I think I'm not alone in that misunderstanding.  Maybe update your question?

Comment: I think u r getting upset, I am sorry for that.My scenario is very clear, my core in one jar and my custom is another jar, I need to invoke my custom logic after executing my core logic, also I have asked is there any feture available to handle this scenario in spring framework

Comment: I'm not upset, but I seem unable to help you. I wish you well finding someone who can.

Answer (score 0):

I am planned to implement my above scenario as per the below approach. Please share is there any other existing approach/design pattern supports my scenario.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author pandian
 *
 */
public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Core core = new Core();
        Map<Object, Object> obj = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        core.create(obj);
    }

    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {

        // TODO implement core business logic
        System.out.println("Core Business Logic Completed");
        try {
            obj = invokeAfter(obj);
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public Map invokeAfter(Map<Object, Object> obj) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        Class params[] = {};
        // TODO below list will be injected using spring configuration in
        // configurable approach
        List<String> afterClassNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        afterClassNameList.add("Custom1");
        afterClassNameList.add("Custom2");

        if (!afterClassNameList.isEmpty()) {
            for (String className : afterClassNameList) {
                System.out.println("Class Name::" + className);
                Class thisClass = Class.forName(className);
                Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
                Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("create", params);
                obj = (Map<Object, Object>) thisMethod.invoke(iClass, obj);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

class Custom1 {
    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {
    // TODO implement custom business logic
    return obj;
    }
}

class Custom2 {
    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {
    // TODO implement custom business logic    
    return obj;
    }
}
```